# How to switch Tabs without Animating Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application with a stack of Fragments added on top of each other.

The Fragments are animated to slide in when opened, and slide out when popped from the backstack. Here's a sample of where I open each `Fragment`:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,0,0,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.add(R.id.examplecontainer, examplefragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The animations work as expected, and everything is good.. except that my App also has a couple more Tabs managed by a `FragmentTabHost`.
When I switch to another Tab and come back, I want the top Fragment to appear without any animations. Instead, it slides in again.

Is there any way to disable animations when switching between tabs on `FragmentTabHost`? Or any way to remove/change the custom animations set to a fragment?

Thank you in advance for any hints/suggestions.

Comment: what if you remove the `ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,0,0,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);` or just put `ft.setCustomAnimation(null));`? Does it work?

Comment: what I'm trying to do here is animate the fragments when they are called, but not when `FragmentTabHost` switches between them.. sorry if it was unclear. Your suggestion removes the animation when the fragments are called..